# Array manipulation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I have an Array and I want to check the data in it with an if block and mark it if it exists in the array.

```
doc.setFontSize(9);
doc.text("Açıklama",6,57);
doc.text("Hastaya Yapılan Uygulama :",6,64);
doc.text("Kullanılan İlaçlar",6,69);
var explanation_application = document.getElementById("explanation_application").value;
textlines = doc.setFontSize(9).splitTextToSize(explanation_application,90);
doc.text(textlines,48,57).value;

doc.setFontSize(8);
doc.text("İzolasyon Durumu:",136,66);

doc.setFontSize(8);
doc.text("Solunum İzolasyonu",163,60);
var checkBox = new jspdf.AcroFormCheckBox();
var checkBoxTxt = document.getElementById("txt").value;
var splitTxt = checkBoxTxt.split(",");
for (let i = 0; i < splitTxt.length; i++){
// for (var state in splitTxt){
    if(splitTxt[i] == 'solunum_izolasyonu') {
       
        checkBox.appearanceState = 'On';
    }
    else {
        
        checkBox.appearanceState = 'Off';
    }
}
checkBox.readOnly = false;
checkBox.fieldName = "Solunum İzolasyonu";
checkBox.Rect = [191, 58, 2, 2];
checkBox.value = 'solunum_izolasyonu';
doc.addField(checkBox);

doc.setFontSize(8);
doc.text("Damlacık İzolasyonu",163,66);
var checkBox1 = new jspdf.AcroFormCheckBox();
var checkBoxTxt1 = document.getElementById("txt").value;
var splitTxt1 = checkBoxTxt1.split(",");
for (let i = 0; i < splitTxt1.length; i++){
    // for (var state in splitTxt){
    if(splitTxt1[i] == 'damlacik_izolasyonu') {
        
        checkBox1.appearanceState = 'On';
    }
    else {
        
        checkBox1.appearanceState = 'Off';
    }
}
checkBox1.readOnly = false;
checkBox1.fieldName = "Damlacık İzolasyonu";
checkBox1.Rect = [191, 64, 2, 2];
checkBox.value = 'damlacik_izolasyonu';
doc.addField(checkBox1);

doc.setFontSize(8);
doc.text("Temas İzolasyonu",163,72);
var checkBox2 = new jspdf.AcroFormCheckBox();
var checkBoxTxt2 = document.getElementById("txt").value;
var splitTxt2 = checkBoxTxt2.split(",");
for (let i = 0; i< splitTxt2.length; i++){
    // for (var state in splitTxt){
    if(splitTxt2[i] == 'temas_izolasyonu') {
        
        checkBox2.appearanceState = 'On';
    }
    else {
        
        checkBox2.appearanceState = 'Off';
    }
}
checkBox2.readOnly = false;
checkBox2.fieldName = "Temas İzolasyonu";
checkBox2.Rect = [191, 70, 2, 2];
checkBox.value = 'temas_izolasyonu';
doc.addField(checkBox2);
```

When I run my code like above, even though there are 2 data in the array, only 1 is marked.I'm new to this field, and what I want to do here is to pull the ids of the checkboxes marked on a form and display it on a pdf. Here I am doing this process using the jsPdf module, but after reaching this stage, I had a problem with the marking point, I would be glad if you could help with this.

Comment: @Yogi Questions which lack details should be closed pending the inclusion of the details (we have a close reason for this), not answered.

Comment: There are 3 checkboxes in the form, I keep the ids of these checkboxes in a textarea, for example, respiratory_isolation, contact_isolation, then I have this text area data checkBoxTxt = document.getElementById("txt").value; I'm pulling in the form and converting it to an array with the split method. 
Then I want to check if such data exists in this array by using an if block with the data in this array and have it marked on the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over the array and resetting it if it has a value. To make your code work it would need to look something like

```js
let hasText = false;
for (let i = 0; i< splitTxt2.length; i++){
    if(splitTxt2[i] == 'temas_izolasyonu') {
        hasText = true;
        // have a match, no need to keep looping so exit
        break;
    }
}
checkBox.appearanceState = hasText ? 'On' : 'Off';
```

And the cleanest solution is includes

```js
const hasText = splitTxt2.includes('solunum_izolasyonu');
checkBox.appearanceState = hasText ? 'On' : 'Off';
```

Comment: @Yogi The question did not lack detail. Unsure why you deleted your answer.

Comment: Hi Bro, can you help me out here please?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/74080646/15916627